# How to fill a Spinner with a Cursor after API level 11?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have found lots of answers on SO and other websites about how to fill a `Spinner` with a `Cursor`, but all of them use the deprectated `SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, int, String[], int[])` constructor to do that. No one seems to describe how to do it with API level 11 and above.

The API tells me to use the `LoaderManager`, but I'm not sure about how to use that.

Comment: I would suggest implementing your own CursorAdapter instead of using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: Thanks @DoctororDrive, your comment is a good one. You may consider magically turn it into an answer, you'd win at least 25 points from me, if you take the time to breifly describe how to create a custom `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest implementing your own CursorAdapter instead of using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Implementing a CursorAdapter is no harder than implementing any other Adapter.
CursorAdapter extends BaseAdapter, and getItem(), getItemId() methods are already overriden for you and return the real values.
It's recommended to use the CursorAdapter from support library (android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter) if you do support pre-Honeycomb. If you are only after 11, just use the android.widget.CursorAdapter
Mind that you don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged() when you call swapCursor(newCursor);

```
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;

public final class CustomAdapter
        extends CursorAdapter
{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super(context, null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    }


    // here is where you bind the data for the view returned in newView()
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor c)
    {

        //just get the data directly from the cursor to your Views.

        final TextView address = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_item_address);
        final TextView title = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);

        final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        final String addressValue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));

        title.setText(name);
        address.setText(addressValue);
    }

    // here is where you create a new view
    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> No one seems to describe how to do it with API level 11 and above.

The documentation does, by [showing you a non-deprecated constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29) that is the same as the one you are trying to use, with a `int flags` extra parameter. Pass `0` for the flags if none of the available flag values are useful to you.